# MessageBox in Out-of-Process COM Server

Tags: c++, com

When you have a console based client and a COM Server, can you call ::MessageBox(...) from the COM Server and expect it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but in  some cases the box will be shown on another desktop and effectively block the calling thread, so you better not try this other than for debugging purposes.

Comment: You can make sure the message box ownership is correct by setting the parent parameter to the console HWND, instead of NULL (desktop HWND). See `http://support.microsoft.com/kb/124103`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WTSSendMessage` function (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383842.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683502.aspx) instead of `MessageBox`.

To get the session id `SessionId` you can use `WTS_CURRENT_SESSION` or `WTSEnumerateSessions` or `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId` or `GetTokenInformation` with `TokenSessionId` and a clients token received during client impersonation. All depends on the scenarios which you have.